# Excel on exit and macro run: 'Code execution has been interupted'

Tags: excel

I am getting a 'Code execution has been interrupted' message on exit from excel intermittently of late.  And its frequency is increasing.  End allows me to leave excel, but once I get the message, my machine must be rebooted to allow for excel to open and run macros again.  This intermittent message does come up with basic excel usage at exit, and is not limited to excel sessions following VBA macros use.  Has anyone seen this or have a solution.  It is getting very annoying.

Comment: I have seen this behavior before, and although I do not know the exact cause, I am very certain that it is caused by an Excel add-in that I have installed.

Comment: any ideas which, I use solver, Analysis ToolPak (+ -VBA), and euro currency tools (installed but not used)

Comment: The add-in was a third-party add-in that pulls data from the third party's web service (and is somewhat poorly implemented).  I have not had any trouble with microsoft add-ins.  You can always try disabling the add-ins to see if the behavior disappears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have came across this issue few times during the development of one complex Excel VBA app. Sometimes Excel started to break VBA object quite randomly. And the only remedy was to reboot machine. After reboot, Excel usually started to act normally.

Soon I have found out that solution to this issue is to hit CTRL+Break once when macro is NOT running. Maybe this can help to you too.